# Subir el punto de inserción

Tags: vba, screen

estoy intentando hacer una rutina en VBA que, dentro de un documento de Word, detecte la posición del punto de inserción (posición del cursor) en coordenadas de la pantalla (no en coordadas de línea, párrafo, etc., del propio documento). No vale una función como GetCursorPos de "user32.dll" u otras que devuelvan la posición del puntero, pues quiero la del cursor y generalmente no coincidirán.

El objetivo, por si mi estrategia fuera ineficiente y se puede conseguir de otra manera, es una rutina que obtenga la coordenada X de la posición del cursor en la pantalla y, en caso de que dicha posición esté en un rango determinado (por ejemplo, en la zona de las cinco líneas de más abajo de la pantalla), haga un scroll subiendo el documento para que la línea con el cursor pase a ser la línea más alta en la pantalla.

Comment: De acuerdo, entonces no tiene nada que ver con los cuadros seleccionados

Comment: Me sorprende que GetCursorPos de "user32" no funcione, ¿viste el [tutorial de Ryan Wells](https://wellsr.com/vba/2015/excel/vba-get-cursor-position-macro/)?

Comment: No, si GetCursorPos funciona perfectamente. El problema es que entrega la posición del puntero, pero yo quiero la del cursor

Comment: Aunque esta pregunta no ha despertado gran interés, dado que he encontrado yo mismo la solución la pego aquí por si resulta de utilidad para alguien.

Comment: Muy bien ! No olvide llamarme con el "@pseudo" la proxima vez para ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

Aunque la pregunta no ha despertado gran interés en función de las falta de respuestas recibidas, dado que he encontrado yo mismo la solución la pego aquí por si resulta de utilidad para alguien.

Se trata de utilizar los métodos GetPoint (para saber dónde está el cursor -no el puntero- en coordenadas de la pantalla) y SmallScroll (para desplazar horizontalmente la ventana) en función del resultado de la primera.